# Mysql SELECT statement to return only rows where/if a given number of cols are not null

Tags: mysql, sql

So what I'm trying to accomplish is a select all in a table, but I only want rows where at least 3 columns/values are set and not null (they could possibly be set to 0 though), out of 5 columns.

I've tried a bunch of stuff with IF but in vain. I don't know if it's even possible.

It seems pretty straightforward but I just can't seem to find the right logic.

Comment: what have your tried so far, please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL()` and add the results:

```
SELECT * from Table 
WHERE ISNULL(c1) + ISNULL(c2) + ISNULL(c3) + ISNULL(c4) + ISNULL(c5) <= 2
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6df63

`ISNULL()` documentation: [Returns `1` when the column is null, `0` otherwise.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)